# How can I blend / flllet two objects of different shape?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I have two objects of different shapes with complex forms but they can be approximated with something like this:

[image]

How can I make that the "cube" blends nicely into the cone (sometimes this is called filleting)?

I tried with metaballs but these don't work on different shapes. Also I tried to sculpt but it cannot be done very precisely and symmetrically.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: See [proportional editing] here at BSE.  Increase your vertex density on the cube with [loop cuts].  A suggestion is to clarify you question by more pictures and showing existing vertex density.

Comment: Subdivide the cube many times to match the cylinder's vertices number, then join the cube with cylinder with *Ctrl+J*. In Edit Mode join the vertices of the two objects with **bridge tool**.

Answer (score 3):

**Increase vertex density and Loop Tools Circle, Bridge**

[image]

Various Stages of Editing.

- Cube in Edit mode, Loop Cut on twice in X and Y Planes.  Delete Middle Squares of vertices
- Think about vertex count of target Cylinder
- Select Perimeter of hole and Loop Tools Circle in Tool Panel
- Extrude in Z Axis
- Loop Cut and Shape with Proportional Edit
- The result is compatible with another Cylinder with same vertex count.
- The Cylinder is not shown above, [Join] two separate objects if necessary
- Use Bridge Tool to connect to perimeter of Cylinder
- Bridge examples can be found by searching here at BSE

Comment: Note that Loop Tools is an addon and might not be enabled by default

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ***Bridge Edge Loops*** tool to do it.
[image]
[image]

Delete  the bottom face of the *cube* and the top one of a *cylinder*. Subdivide the *cube* many times to match the *cylinder*'s vertices number. In *Object Mode* join the cube with cylinder with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. In *Edit Mode* extrude and scale the bottom edge loop of a *cube* inwards (to make the subsurf crease work), then join the vertices of the two objects with ***bridge tool*** (activate the ***Loop Tools*** add on in *User Preferences*, then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *'bridge'*). The rest is a matter of adding an extra geometry or rearranging it to make the *subsurf* work properly (two examples pictured in the first .jpeg and in a .blend here: [image]).
[image]